# With what structure do you manage the graphics of a game?

Tags: java, libgdx, architecture, graphics

Im currently trying to program a little game (in Java - Libgdx; if thats necessary).

I currently use a `GameWorld` and a `GameRenderer`, the `GameRenderer` just getting all the info it needs from the `GameWorld` object and calling a method for every different class there is (for example `drawPlayer()`, `drawWorld()` etc.).

Should I let my actors draw themselves or encapsulate the data inside of another class and then pass an object of it to the `GameRenderer`?

Comment: Each of those bullet points is a separate question in its own right; for example the first one is something we've had a few duplicate questions for already. You should ask each one on its own, with the possible exception of the last, which is just too broad (there is no "best". That one you might have better luck asking at a discussion forum like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).